# logstash : http input takes only first line (with csv filter)

Tags: csv, elastic-stack

i'm newbie to elk stack and trying to monitor logs send through http. I have below logstash configuration. But it only read and send first line to elastic search although I send multiple lines in my http POST request body (Im using chromes DHC plugin to send http request to logstash). Please help me to read full data and send them to elastic search.

```
input {
  http {
    host => "127.0.0.1" # default: 0.0.0.0
    port => 8081 # default: 8080
    threads => 10
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["posTimestamp","posCode","logLevel","location","errCode","errDesc","detail"]
  }
  date {
    match => ["posTimestamp", "ISO8601"]
  }
  mutate {
     strip => ["posCode", "logLevel", "location", "errCode", "errDesc" ]
     remove_field => [ "path", "message", "headers" ]
  }
}

output { 
    elasticsearch {
      protocol => "http"
      host => "localhost"
      index => "temp"
    }
    stdout { 
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Sample data:
2015-08-24T05:21:40.468,352701060205140,ERROR,Colombo,ERR_01,INVALID_CARD,Testing POS errors
2015-08-24T05:21:41.468,352701060205140,ERROR,Colombo,ERR_01,INVALID_CARD,Testing POS errors
2015-08-24T05:23:40.468,81021320,ERROR,Colombo,ERR_01,INVALID_CARD,Testing POS errors
2015-08-25T05:23:50.468,352701060205140,ERROR,Colombo,ERR_02,TIME_OUT,Testing POS errors

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this by adding split filter.

split {
}